# Nintendo 64, mupen64plus: cannot configure controller

Tags: gamepad, emulation

I received an nintendo 64 usb controller and tried to use it to play (this one http://www.ebay.com/itm/Retrolink-Classic-Nintendo-64-USB-Controller-for-PC-and-MAC-BLACK-NEW-/360701283915?pt=US_Video_Game_Controllers&hash=item53fb78ce4b ).

So I put it,used this tutorial to install it http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=338457 and I can see with jstest that it's working. So I installed mupen64plus and M64Py for the gui, so the gui recognize my controller, but I cannot use it.
I saw on the post [How do you configure mupen64plus controls?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206559/how-do-you-configure-mupen64plus-controls) that I'm using the same controller than on the image tbe DragonRise inc one, but every time I change the controls and press enter or click on close it's just change all the controls by something per default like this:

> DPad R = "key(100)"
>
> DPad L = "key(97)"
>
> DPad D = "key(115)"
>
> DPad U = "key(119)"
>
> Start = "key(13)"
>
> Z Trig = "key(122)"
>
> B Button = "key(306)"
>
> A Button = "key(304)"
>
> C Button R = "key(108)"
>
> C Button L = "key(106)"
>
> C Button D = "key(107)"
>
> C Button U = "key(105)"
>
> R Trig = "key(99)"
>
> L Trig = "key(120)"
>
> Mempak switch = "key(44)"
>
> Rumblepak switch = "key(46)"
>
> X Axis = "key(276,275)"
>
> Y Axis = "key(273,274)"

Normally the buttons should be like button 1,2,3 etc

I tried with the gui and without the gui but I cannot make this controller workinf :/
Thanks for reading and sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

You should ask this question on the [**mupen64 forums**](http://www.emutalk.net/forums/50-Mupen64), asking us will get you nowhere.

*It's probably mupen64s fault.*