# Running mupen64plus as root

Tags: permissions

Ok so I have seen a lot of these questions asked, and I have not been able to figure out certain details on how to do this. I have Ubuntu 14.04, and I am trying to use my xbox controller to play the mupen64plus. I downloaded the xboxdrv and the controller registers on the computer. at least enough to calibrate it. It however does not register in mupen64plus. So I read an article  [ [How do you configure mupen64plus controls?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206559/how-do-you-configure-mupen64plus-controls) ]. This was extremely helpful. However I cannot bring the confg file up in the termianl, due to a Permissions error. So I tried to find the file in the GUI and edit the File itself, but It wont save any changes. It just tells me I do not have permission. So I right clicked and looked at the permissions in the proprieties section, and sure enough I do not, It also wont let me change that. 
  So does anybody have any sample code for how to run this program in root. I have been trying to figure this out. something I can possible just copy and paste into my termianl and get this done with. I think the actual path is usr/share/gaming/mupen64plus, however I am not in front of my system right now to double check.

Comment: If anyone answers this I expect a big fat warning regarding using this software as "root". Oh and this package IS in the software center. I highly doubt "root" is needed.  All you need to do is set the correct permissions. I would suggest editing this question to focus on fixing the permissions error you get.

Comment: Can you use `sudo` to open the config file?